# Pandas read_html() returns 'nan' on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to scrape a website but it returns a whole column with `'nan'` values instead of the proper ones. I have tried changing several `read_html()` parameters, such as flavor, converters, and na_values without success. I noticed that the html code of the troubled column differs in that the rest of them are `'td class='` type, while the one not being read properly reads `'td data-behavior='`. When I simply copy/paste the table into excel, everything is pasted ok. I would kindly appreciate any help.

I tried changing some parameters on `read_html()` without success. I have also tried to get the table using lxml/xpath and didn't succeed either.

```
week_data = pd.read_html('https://www.espn.co.uk/nfl/fixtures/_/week/2/seasontype/1',
                          converters={'time': str})
```

The column should have strings containing the time of the match.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add data then you can't get it with panda, requests/urllib, lxml/beautifulsoup because they can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control web browser which will run JavaScript and later you can get HTML. [Selenium-Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Thanks! I have never used selenium but I will look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're embedding the date time in the data-date attribute so another option rather than resorting to selenium is simply to pull that attribute out and stick it in the td element using beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import dateutil
from datetime import datetime

espn_page = requests.get('https://www.espn.co.uk/nfl/fixtures/_/week/2/seasontype/1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(espn_page.content, 'html.parser')
espn_schedule = soup.find('div', {'class': 'main-content'})
for td in espn_schedule.find_all('td', {'data-behavior': 'date_time'}):
    utc = dateutil.parser.parse(td.get('data-date'))
    localtime = utc.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz())
    td.string = localtime.strftime("%I:%M")


df = pd.read_html(str(espn_schedule))
print(df[0].columns)
print(df[0][df[0].columns[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I highly appreciate your sharing of knowledge.

Comment: It works great, but I need further help, if you can. I posted it below.

Comment: Clockwatcher, is there a good manual or reference text so that I can study in more detail how BS works? Thanks again.

Comment: @gosci - I'm sure you've already found it but the beautiful soup documentation covers pretty much anything you'd ever want to know about it  -- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Yes, I found everything I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly, but I rather need the text contained after the 'href' element, which is '6:00 PM':

So I modified your code like this:

```
for td in espn_schedule.find_all('a', {'data-dateformat': 'time1'}):
    td.string = td.get('href')
```

And I succesfully get to the element I want, except that I don't know how to extract the text after it (which is '6:00 PM'). How can I do that?

Comment: the data-date is given in UTC time.  So your 6:00pm may be my 4:00pm.   To get it to do what your'e after, you just need to convert the given UTC to your local time.  The easiest way to do that is with the python-dateutil pip package.  I modified my post above to format it with just the local time.